# Django - Passing POST data from view to view and bugs with form validation.

Tags: django, validation, post, django-forms, django-views

I am changing passwords for accounts .I am getting Username and password from first view and passing it on sencond view it works fine but when it comes to second view form validation. It redirects with error to the first view's form. That's my  problem.

My goal is if 2nd authetication fails then discard the data (username and password) dont change the password. One more thing I dont want the user to access second view by get request.

```
def first_view(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
  form=firstForm(request.POST) # for getting username password
  if form.is_valid():
   return second_view(request) # Don't want HttpResponse here. To send POST request.
   #Sending username and password data in POST request.
 else:
  form=firstForm()
 return render(request,'template1.html',{'form':form})
```

This is 2nd authentication by sending Text Code on phone

```
def second_view(request):
 if request.method === 'POST':
  form=secondForm(request.POST) # Single field - Code recieved on phone 
  username=request.POST['username']
  password=request.POST['password']
  code=GetRandomNumber() # Creates a random number to send on phone. 
  SendText(code,numer) # Sends code on number
  if form.is_valid(): # HERE IT REDIRECTS TO THE FIRST VIEW FORM WITH ERROR
   if code==request.POST['code']:
    HttpResponse('Succeess') 
  else:
   HttpResponse('Not allowed')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the django session in this case. For example:

**First View**

1. Check username/password in FirstForm in first_view when POST
2. IF credentials are OK -- save some state in session
3. Send a code to user
4. Redirect to second_view

**Secod View**

5. Check previous saved state in session
6. Check code in SecondForm in second_view when POST
7. If code is OK -- Success!

Something like this.

Comment: Your solution is right user will authenticated. Reason to do above code is Step 4 is a Redirect  that is GET request. I dont want to pop up the second_view if user hit second_view url. It will be a meaningless window. In this case  I cant use decorator like @login_required. Is there any way I can prevent user from accessing second_view  if it is not initiated by first_view?

Comment: Pay your attention at points (2) and (5). Point (2) -- you just save in session a flag ``request.session['first_view_ok'] = True``(just for example, also you can save in session username/user_pk/etc) which indicates that user passed correctly the (1) point. Do not authenticate -- just store a flag. As for (5) -- you should check if ``request.session['first_view_ok'] == True`` go to the (6), otherwise raise an error "Authentication in FirstView required!".